# Vue cli - TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli, dotenv

I'm trying to use `process.env` in my vue app. I've created two `.env` files one for production `.env.production` and another for dev `.env.development`. the two files are in the root of my vue project but vue cli will ignore them. I have created an envoirment variable that I'm calling in my `Home.vue` component to set the path of an image for the dev/production that will be different. the problem is that after the build when I run my app to test it I will get this error

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'env' of undefined
```

and it's related to the path set into the src tag of the image I want to load

```html
<img class="img-fluid" :src="`${process.env.VUE_APP_PATH_START}/img/background.jpg`">
```

my `.env` files looks like this
development env file

```js
VUE_APP_PATH_START = ../assets/
```

production env file

```js
VUE_APP_PATH_START = /
```

Is there any reason why I get this error in my build and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to define it as a computed property using require function :

```
computed:{
    background(){
        return require("`${process.env.VUE_APP_PATH_START}/img/background.jpg`")
  }
}
```

template :

```
 <img class="img-fluid" :src="background"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed property has mentioned above, but you will have to duplicate the code every time u need it, so i believe a better approach is to set a state to this variable like this

```
 state: {
    appStartPath: process.env.VUE_APP_PATH_START,
    ///
 }
```

and then u can instantiate in image src like this

```
<img class="img-fluid" :src="`${$store.state.appStartPath}/img/background.jpg`">
```

or any part of the project like this

```
<div>
  {{ $store.state.appStartPath }}
</div>
```